# Impossible to fully qualify class-name in out-of-class declarator of function definition

Tags: c++, parsing, methods, fully-qualified-naming

This program results in an undesired parsing greediness dead-end:

```
struct float4x4 {};
class C
{
    float4x4 M();
};

float4x4 ::C::M()
{
    return float4x4{};
}
```

> :8:1: error: no member named 'C' in 'float4x4'; did you mean simply 'C'?
>   float4x4 ::C::M()
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Which can be 'fixed' using trailing return type:

```
auto ::C::M() -> float4x4
{}
```

now all good.

So I take it we can't fully qualify the class-name when using heading-return-type declarator syntax?

Comment: As long as C++ ignores the whitespace around `::`, I suppose there is no other way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, check this out https://godbolt.org/z/mt6GHD

Comment: The `::C` part looks like a workaround for some other issue. Otherwise it could have been simply `C` (like the compiler suggests;)

Comment: @rustyx it's just mechanical re-emission of code by a transpiler that doesn't want to execute an ultra complex "find least qualified name" at this position. emitting a FQ-name bypasses lookup completely and is convenient for such tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put brackets to disambiguate:

```
float4x4 (::C::M)()
{
    return float4x4{};
}
```

I cannot really tell you what rule makes this ok, while it is not without the brackets, though I tested with gcc and clang (both `-pedantic`). I would prefer the trailing return type.

Comment: incredible. indeed we can. https://godbolt.org/z/KCFbJZ that's disgusting but it's awesome. Of course in terms of style the trailing is great. But in my case I target a dialect that doesn't support it.