# Is a fully qualified class name down to global scope ever required for out-of-line member function definitions?

Tags: c++, name-lookup, global-scope, qualified-name, scope-resolution-operator

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913331/impossible-to-fully-qualify-class-name-in-out-of-class-declarator-of-function-de) question got me wondering whether it is ever useful/necessary to fully qualify class names (including the global scope operator) in an out-of-class member function definition.

On the one hand, I've never seen this done before (and the syntax to properly do so seems obscure). On the other, C++ name lookup is very non-trivial, so maybe a corner case exists.

**Question:**

Is there ever a case where introducing an out-of-class member function definition by
`ReturnType (::Fully::Qualified::Class::Name::MemberFunctionName)(...) { ... }`
would differ from
`ReturnType Fully::Qualified::Class::Name::MemberFunctionName(...) { ... }` (no global scope `::` prefix)?

<sup>Note that member function definitions must be put into a namespace enclosing the class, so [this](https://godbolt.org/z/68wAXW) is not a valid example.</sup>

Comment: Very curious what the downvoter dislikes about this question. Feedback welcome!

Comment: when the definition is placed in a different namespace than the declaration? Thats what I had in mind for the quesiton you link

Comment: oops, didnt read the smallprint ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That's also what I had in mind, then I tried it and realized it wouldn't work, so I wrote the question (figuring others would wonder too).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *using-directive* can cause `Fully` to be ambiguous without qualification.

```
namespace Foo {
    struct X {
    };
}

using namespace Foo;
struct X {
    void c();
};

void X::c() { } // ambiguous
void ::X::c() { } // OK
```

Answer (score 5):

It's necessary if one is a masochist and enjoys writing stuff like this

```
namespace foo {
    namespace foo {
        struct bar {
            void baz();
        };
    }

   struct bar {
       void baz();
   };

   void foo::bar::baz() {
   }

   void (::foo::bar::baz)() {
   }
}
```

One can of course write the second overload as `foo::foo::bar::baz` in global scope, but the question was whether or not the two declarations can have a different meaning. I wouldn't recommend writing such code.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a valid answer, and doesn't even need a `using`. Nice to have different cases highlighted!

Answer (score 2):

If a using directive is used then there can be a confusing code.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace N1
{
    struct A
    {
        void f() const;
    };      
}

using namespace N1;

void A::f() const { std::cout << "N1::f()\n"; }

struct A
{
    void f() const;
};

void ::A::f() const { std::cout << "::f()\n"; }

int main() 
{
    N1::A().f();
    ::A().f();

    return 0;
}
```

So for readability this qualified name

```
void ::A::f() const { std::cout << "::f()\n"; }
```

shows precisely where the function is declared.